# need help recursively rendering images from subfolders in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

We have a Wordpress site that shows images from 6 webcams. It was designed to show the second most recent images. 
The images are uploaded to the WordPress site in folders by camera, day, hour, min
the site retains the last hours worth of images. Id like to generate a wordpress page that will for example show every image in the camera6 folder that we have.

here is the folder structure of the uploads 
wp-content/uploads/cameras/Camera4/2020-05-02/001/jpg/13/12/00[R][0@0][0].jpg
id like to be able to parse the folders under wp-content/uploads/cameras/Camera4 and show all the images on a single page.  There are about 3 images per minute. a cron cleans up the folders at 10 past every hour.

In case it helps here is the code that shows the 6 most recent images

```
 $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $camera_dir_1 = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/cameras/Camera1/$today/001/jpg/$hourMin/$minute");
        $camera_dir_2 = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/cameras/Camera2/$today/001/jpg/$hourMin/$minute");
        $camera_dir_3 = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/cameras/Camera3/$today/001/jpg/$hourMin/$minute");
        $camera_dir_4 = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/cameras/Camera4/$today/001/jpg/$hourMin/$minute");
        $camera_dir_5 = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/cameras/Camera5/$today/001/jpg/$hourMin/$minute");
        $camera_dir_6 = ( $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/cameras/Camera6/$today/001/jpg/$hourMin/$minute");

        $files_array_1 = scandir($camera_dir_1);
        $files_array_2 = scandir($camera_dir_2);
        $files_array_3 = scandir($camera_dir_3);
        $files_array_4 = scandir($camera_dir_4);
        $files_array_5 = scandir($camera_dir_5);
        $files_array_6 = scandir($camera_dir_6);

        $second_most_image_camera_1=get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/cameras/Camera1/'.$today.'/001/jpg/'.$hourMin.'/'.$minute.'/'.$files_array_1["2"];
        $second_most_image_camera_2=get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/cameras/Camera2/'.$today.'/001/jpg/'.$hourMin.'/'.$minute.'/'.$files_array_2["2"];
        $second_most_image_camera_3=get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/cameras/Camera3/'.$today.'/001/jpg/'.$hourMin.'/'.$minute.'/'.$files_array_3["2"];
        $second_most_image_camera_4=get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/cameras/Camera4/'.$today.'/001/jpg/'.$hourMin.'/'.$minute.'/'.$files_array_4["2"];
        $second_most_image_camera_5=get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/cameras/Camera5/'.$today.'/001/jpg/'.$hourMin.'/'.$minute.'/'.$files_array_5["2"];
        $second_most_image_camera_6=get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/cameras/Camera6/'.$today.'/001/jpg/'.$hourMin.'/'.$minute.'/'.$files_array_6["2"];
      ?>

<ul class="home_camera_sum">
<div style="text-align:center;">
 <br><br>
<li><img src="<?php echo $files_array_1; ?>"  target="new" class="image" 
alt="camera images"></li> 
<li><img src="<?php echo $second_most_image_camera_4; ?>"  target="new" class="image" alt="camera image"></li> <li><img src="<?php echo $second_most_image_camera_3; ?>"  target="new" class="image" alt="camera image"></li> <P>
<li><img src="<?php echo $second_most_image_camera_2; ?>"  target="new" class="image" alt="camera image"></li>  <li><img src="<?php echo $second_most_image_camera_1; ?>"  target="new" class="image" alt="camera image"></li> <P>
<li><img src="<?php echo $second_most_image_camera_5; ?>"  target="new" class="image" alt="camera image"></li> <li><img src="<?php echo $second_most_image_camera_6; ?>"  target="new" class="image" alt="camera image"></li>
 </ul>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <?php`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `glob` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

It takes a pattern, and returns all files that match that pattern, for instance:

```php
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++) {
    $image_files = glob($upload_dir['basedir'] . '/cameras/Camera' . $i . '/**/*.jpg');

    // print all images in folder CameraX
    foreach ($image_files as $filename) {
        echo '<BR>' . $filename;
    }
}
```

That should work—or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, testing now. 

I think you are missing a ( on the 4th line ----

- I've managed to remove the parse errors and display the header and footer but dont yet see images https://www.114thrc.org/test-images/

Comment: Hard to know what's going on, my point is mainly that `glob` should allow you to get those images without all those loops. What is the thing printing..? What's in `$filename`?